# axis web service logging issue

Tags: java, web-services, logging, axis

in my axis webservice client project i have **client-config.wsdd** file in which i use **java:org.apache.axis.handlers.LogHandler** which is

```
    <deployment name="defaultClientConfig"
   xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/"
   xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">

   <handler name="log"
      type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.LogHandler">
      <parameter name="LogHandler.fileName" value="../logs/xyz-Axis.log" />
   </handler>

   <globalConfiguration>
      <parameter name="disablePrettyXML" value="false" />
      <requestFlow>
         <handler type="log" />
      </requestFlow>
      <responseFlow>
         <handler type="log" />
      </responseFlow>
   </globalConfiguration>

   <transport name="http"
      pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender" />
   <transport name="local"
      pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.local.LocalSender" />
   <transport name="java"
      pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.java.JavaSender" />
</deployment>
```

for generating log file so i can see request and response of webservice.
but some how it's not working, or i can't able to find it please help

Answer (score 1):

you need to define `client-config.wsdd` into root level of project and need to change in

```
 <handler name="log"
  type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.LogHandler">
  <parameter name="LogHandler.fileName" value="xyz-Axis.log"/>
```

so the xyz-Axis.log will generate at same level of client-config.wsdd